# how to return an array of objects from a number?

Tags: javascript

You must create a function called `arrayOfObjects` that receives a number as a parameter and returns an array of objects that have a property called `value` that contains the value of the number and its predecessors.

example

```
ArrayOfObjects(3)
```

should return:

```
[{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}]
```

my code

```
function arrObj(number){
  let newArray = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<number; i++){
    newArray.push(number.object)
  }
  console.log(newArray)
}

arrObj(5)
```

I'm new with objects, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To insert into `newArray` you need to add an object with a key of `value` and value of the incremental index. Here is a snippet that would do that.

```js
function arrObj(number){
  let newArray = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<number; i++){
    // Push {value:number}
    newArray.push({value:i+1})
  }
  console.log(newArray)
}

arrObj(5)
```

Comment: Please provide some context and description to the answer.

Comment: I was close, thank you very much!